# Database Size Troubleshooting

Tags: sql-server, datafile, size

I have a SQL Server database and the `.MDF` file is almost 9GB in size. However, the data and indexes only seem to be taking up a little over 1GB. I've shrunk the database (with and without reorganization) and I've shrunk the database files.

What's next? How do I find what is taking up so much space?

Comment: What does "seem to be" mean? How are you measuring this? How did the data file get to 9GB in the first place? If you have removed a bunch of data but it is going to grow again, shrinking it in the short term [is a complete waste of time](http://www.straightpathsql.com/archives/2009/01/dont-touch-that-shrink-button/).

Comment: I'm using this script to measure table sizes. http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=10932 I'm shrinking the database after removing a decade of legacy records. Sure it will grow to that size again, but not for another decade. And in the meantime we can migrate servers without 10GB file transfers.

Comment: `And in the meantime we can migrate servers without 10GB file transfers` --> Have you looked into backup compression ? I assume that you are not transferring the `mdf` files over the network. Backup restore (with compression) is the best way to move your databases to new server.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Kin. I do, however, still think the question is still valid: how do I find out why the DB takes up so much disc space?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment so I'm putting it here.

First try running this:

```
exec sp_msforeachtable 'sp_spaceused [?]'
```

Yes I realize it uses sp_msforeachtable and there are a number of better methods, this is just quick and hopefully "good enough".

At a guess you have a heap (no clustered index) that has a large amount of "unused" space.  I wrote about how to duplicate it [here](http://sqlstudies.com/2014/08/25/the-amazing-never-shrinking-heap/).  If in the list of tables you find one that has a large amount of space shown in the `unused` column then try running this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename REBUILD
```

Fair warning it may take up some space to run the operation but it should free up the excess space in the table.

Comment: Other relevant warnings you might want to add: while not much of an issue for 1Gb worth of data+index for large tables will be a lot of IO, to/from local disks or over the network depending on the configuration, that will slow other processes. Also to stop the process completely blocking other transactions that access the target table use `ALTER TABLE tablename REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON), though not that not all versions/editions of SQL Server support online rebuilds of indexes/heaps.